# UITextField becomeFirstResponder transfers values and properties between cells

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7, uitextfield

So I have what is the apparently ubiquitous setup of having a UITextField inside my own custom subclass of UITableViewCell.  I went ahead and used the storyboard to create a prototype cell with the title and textfield.  I want to focus on the UITextField when you tap anywhere on the cell.

I'm very new to iOS, but I've gone through enough similar questions here to get something that *almost* works.  The cells look exactly like I want them to, and if you tap on the cell, it sets focus on the text field and pulls up the keyboard.  However, if I type something into the text field and then tap on the cell outside the active text field, the text disappears.  If I then tap again, or on another cell, it displays the original/disappeared text in the text field of the tapped cell.  Even stranger, if the original cell has the 'isSecure' property set to YES, then text displayed in the second cell shows up with the black dots, even if it isn't originally set to secure.  The keyboard type, however, doesn't change.

If I tap directly into text fields, they behave exactly as I would expect, no text clearing, no content transfer and no display property transfers.

I would like the text to not clear when I tap on the cell containing the text field, and I'd especially not like to transfer the secure display, but more fundamentally, I'd like to understand why it's acting so strangely.

Code I believe to be relevant:

View controller methods:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"textFieldCell";
    REGTextFieldTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    REGTextFieldParameters *parameters =[self.parameterList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell loadFormContent:parameters];  // Set cell label, placeholder text, keyboard type
    return cell;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    [[(REGTextFieldTableCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] textField] becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

REGTextFieldTableCell.h:

```
#import "REGFormTableCell.h"
#import "REGTextFieldParameters.h"

@interface REGTextFieldTableCell : REGFormTableCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;

- (void)loadFormContent:(REGTextFieldParameters *) params;

@end
```

REGTextFieldTableCell relevant methods:

```
- (void)loadFormContent:(REGTextFieldParameters *) params
{
    self.label.text = params.title;
    self.textField.placeholder = params.title;
    self.textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    if([params.keyboardType isEqual:@"email"])
    {
        self.textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress;
        self.textField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
    }else{
        self.textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
        self.textField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeSentences;
    }
    if(params.isSecure){
        self.textField.secureTextEntry = YES;
        self.textField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
    }
}
```

Sorry if this is a dupe, I've looked for a few hours and haven't found anything close to this.  Also let me know what other code I should include if you're having trouble reproducing.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I figured out how to fix it, though I honestly am not sure why it works:

I commented out this line:

```
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

I'm not sure why it goes haywire when it reloads the rows, but at least I have my solution.